# Getting a combination using a function

Tags: function

I got a problem here. The question is that assuming Z=3, and Y= 4, how do I create a function that returns me a random combination of maybe zzzyyyy or zzyyyzy or any permutation? I did the code below but im quite confused.

```
def combinations(iterable,r):
   pool= tuple(iterable)
   n= len(pool)
   for indices in permutations(range(n), r):
       if sorted(indices)==listed(indices):
           yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)
       return

print(combinations('AAABBB', 4))
```

but i got only

```
output: <generator object combinations at 0x103f81518>
```

Thanks!!

Comment: yeap thanks. i just edited the question

Comment: i really did try and im new to this. how am i supposed to convince you that i did try.. ah forget it im not here to argue with u

Comment: edited and still cant figure it out

Comment: well honestly i have no clue what you're saying cos its already properly spaced. can just give me a mark down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use the `permutations` function in `itertools`. It will generate all possible permutation of the given list (or string). Then use `randrange` in `random` to generate the random number in the range of 0 to the list length, to select any random element in the list.

```
from itertools import permutations
import random

def build_string(z_num, y_num):
    string = ''
    string += 'Z'*z_num
    string += 'Y'*y_num
    return string

string = build_string(3, 4)
perms = [''.join(p) for p in permutations('ZZZYYYY')]
print(perms[random.randrange(0, len(perms))]) # print random permutation
```

Comment: Thanks Andres. Apologies for losing my temper. Am still very new to this and am trying to figure out a lot of things. It's crazy difficult

Comment: I would suggest you to start from simpler task or project. Also, to get better understanding regarding python capabilities, so that you would know what to search in Google or in here. I found that usually most questions has already been answered in one way or another in StackOverflow

Comment: This is not a suitable place for that, we can move to https://chat.stackoverflow.com if you have other unrelated questions.